# Exibir value de input tipo date

Tags: php, html, html5

Tenho o seguinte input:

```
<p>Data Saída:</p>
<input type="date" maxlength="10" id="saida" name="saida" value="29/01/2016"/>
```

Ele está sendo exibido da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quero exiba dentro do input seu **value** e não o **dd/mm/aaaa**

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca o valor que está em $DtSaida

Comment: Ok, está editado.

Comment: use o formato americano de data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema segue código certo:

```
$data_formatada = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $DtSaida);

<input type="date" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return dateMask(this, event);" id="saida" name="saida" value="<?php echo $data_formatada->format('Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para tal basta que o conteúdo da variável **$DtSaida** esteja no formato YYYY-MM-DD vide o exemplo abaixo:

```html
<p>Data Saída:</p><input type="date" maxlength="10" id="saida" name="saida" value="2016-01-16"/>
```

Considerando seu resultado você precisa remover os minutos do print para tal tente algo similar a isso:
echo

```
<p>Data Saída:</p><input type="date" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return dateMask(this, event);" id="saida" name="saida" value="<?php date_format($DtSaida, 'Y-m-d'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: Pois é voltei para o padrão americano pois continua o dd/mm/aaaa no lugar do value. Segue: `<p>Data Saída:</p><input type="date" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return dateMask(this, event);" id="saida" name="saida" value="2016-01-21 00:00:00.000"/>
` pegou valor mas no input continua igual.

Comment: @Kevin.F você precisa formatar a saída adicionei um snippet com o exemplo na resposta acima

Comment: Eu só quero tirar esses caracteres (dd/mm/aaaa) de dentro do input para que apareça o valor que está dentro do value. Segue erro que deu `<p>Data Saída:</p><input type="date" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return dateMask(this, event);" id="saida" name="saida" value="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in 
"/>
`

Comment: qual o tipo da sua variável $DtSaida se for uma string olhe essa referência: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Ela está como INT

Comment: Não faz sentido se ela estiver como int como o output dela seria `2016-01-21 00:00:00.000`?

Comment: Pois é mas está como int

Comment: @Kevin.F porque não coloca o tipo de $DtSaida como datetime?